# Deeplearning4J MultiLayerConfiguration settings for a two class logistic regression model

Tags: java, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, deeplearning4j

I am attempting to build a two class logistic regression model but am unsure of the best method for a two class model.

I am working with data that looks like this:

| Feature a | Feature b | Feature c | ... | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.85 | 0.2 | 0.4 |  | 1.0 |
| 0.05 | 0.3 | 0.1 |  | 0.0 |

With features of range 0-1 and labels of 0 or 1.

I'm currently using this MultiLayerConfiguration:

```
private static final int FEATURES_COUNT = 30;
private static final int CLASSES_COUNT = 2; 
...

MultiLayerConfiguration conf = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder().seed(12345)
        .updater(new Sgd(0.01))
        .seed(1)
        .biasInit(0)
        .list()
        .layer(new DenseLayer.Builder()
            .nIn(FEATURES_COUNT)
            .nOut(50)
            .activation(Activation.SIGMOID)
            .weightInit(new UniformDistribution(0, 1))
            .build())
        .layer(new DenseLayer.Builder()
            .nIn(50)
            .nOut(50)
            .activation(Activation.SIGMOID)
            .weightInit(new UniformDistribution(0, 1))
            .build())
        .layer(new OutputLayer.Builder(LossFunctions.LossFunction.NEGATIVELOGLIKELIHOOD)
            .nOut(2)
            .activation(Activation.SOFTMAX)
            .weightInit(new UniformDistribution(0, 1))
            .build())
```

Is this the best way to build the model?

Also, when running for a couple minutes the model only predicts the label 0.

```
   0   1
   ---------
   247   0 | 0 = 0
   253   0 | 1 = 1
```

I can generate as much data as needed, as well, and am currently using a dataset of 6,000 with a batch size of 500.

How would you recommended I improve my settings/model?

Thank you in advance for any recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid setting a distribution for your model unless you have a specific goal. That massively affects the performance of your model. The default XAVIER is fine for most use cases.

You also don't typically want model weights initialized between 0 and 1. That's too big and prevents the model from learning.

A logistic regresion is also not what you presented here. You created a  3 layer MLP. If you want to just have a logistic regression, that's going to be a 1 layer neural net with either softmax or sigmoid. That should simplify your tuning quite a bit.

Of note is when you get further in, normalization of your data will also matter.

Lastly, for your data setup, ensure that your labels are  each 0s and 1s. If you have sigmoid on the output, you'll want 1 output as either 0 or 1. If you have 2 then you'll want 2 columns of 0/1 where 1 is the label. The column index of 1 will be what you want the target label to be.